# AppSync: pipeline resolver #return null result

Tags: aws-appsync

I'm successfully using a pipeline resolver to persist a parent/child relationship, except when the list of child items is empty and I `#return` early.

I'm guessing the issue is around my response mappers and use of `$ctx.prev` vs `$ctx.result` but I can't figure it out.

The pipeline looks like this:

- BEFORE template: `{}`
- Function 1:

  - request = `PutItem` the parent
  - response = `$utils.toJson($ctx.result)`
- Function 2:

  - request = `TransactWriteItems` (`foreach UpdateItem`) the children
  - response = `$utils.toJson($ctx.prev.result)`
- AFTER template: `$utils.toJson($ctx.prev.result)`

When I call the mutation with

```
{"parentAttribute":"foo", "children": [{"childAttribute": "bar"}]}
```

I get a good response like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createFoo": {
      "parentAttribute": "foo",
      "children": [
        {
          "childAttribute": "bar"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If no children, Function 2 request mapper does `#return` to avoid "TransactWriteItems must have at least one operation" error.

In this scenario I am hoping for the above response to the mutation, just with `children: []`
Instead, I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createFoo": null
  }
}
```

The data has been written correctly; if I query it I get back the parent with empty list of children.

How do I get this pipeline to execute so that it returns the combined parent+child data whether the child array is populated or not?

---

### Detail

The schema is something like:

```
type Foo {
  id: String!
  attr1: String
  bars: [Bar]
}

type Bar {
  id: String!
  attr2: String
}

type Mutation {
  createFoo(foo: Foo): Foo
}
```

And a dynamodb representation like this:

| pk | sk | attr1 | attr2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FOO#1 | METADATA#FOO#1 | Lorem |  |
| FOO#1 | BAR#1 |  | Ipsum |

While the pipeline looks like:

`before.vtl`

```
{}
```

`createParent-request.vtl`

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
        "pk" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(...),
        "sk" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(...)
    },
    "attributeValues" : {
        "data" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(...)
    }
}
```

`createParent-response.vtl`

```
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

$utils.toJson($ctx.result)
```

`createChildren-request.vtl`

```
#if($ctx.args.fooInput.children.size() > 0) 
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "operation": "TransactWriteItems",
    "transactItems": [
    #foreach( $child in $ctx.args.fooInput.children )
       {
           "table": "${table}",
           "operation": "UpdateItem",
           "key": {
                "pk" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(...),
                "sk" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(...)
           },
           "update": {
               "expression": "SET #data = :data",
               "expressionNames": {
                   "#data":  "data"
                   
               },
               "expressionValues": {
                    ":data":     
                       $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(...)
                   
               }
           }
       }

       #if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
    #end
       
    ]
}
#else
    #return 
#end
```

`createChildren-response.vtl`

```
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

$utils.toJson($ctx.prev.result)
```

`after.vtl`

```
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

$utils.toJson($ctx.prev.result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For the expected behaviour, one needs the 'after' mapper to return the necessary JSON to populate the overall mutation response. In my example above, `after.vtl` needs to return a `parent` and nothing else matters (in particular, the result of the individual function response mappers).

I ended up putting the output of the 'create parent' operation into `ctx.stash` then returning `ctx.stash` in `after.vtl`, setting the other resolvers to `{}`.

Note that, if your response has subtypes (with their own resolvers) and you return it sparse, AppSync will call the resolver. In the context of my example, it's enough to return the `parent` without any `children` and then the normal query resolver for "get children of a parent" will execute to populate the final response.

Comment: Do you have a working example of your solution?